# Vuetify v-data-table add complex data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am working on v-data-table. I couldn't figure out how to process the information from the backend. Could you help?

i tried this code but i get vue.runtime.esm.js:1897 TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="products" class="elevation-1" :search="search">
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.category}}</td>
....
            <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(props.item)">
          <v-icon class="mx-0 primary--text white--text">edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
          <v-icon class="mx-0 red--text white--text">delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

data from api

```json
{
   "items": [
       {
          "name":"test",
          "id":1,
          "category":"test"
       }
   ],
}
```

Comment: Please define "does not work". Perhaps you should try `:items="products.items"` ?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Maybe IVO's answer is sufficient though.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks it's done

Answer (score 0):

The data you receive from the API is stored in the `items` array

```
data(){
  return {
    items: []
```

If that is the case then you will need to do this:

```
v-data-table :items="items"
```

and **not** `products` like you have above.

[Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/)